# VHDL syntax to drop multiplication remainder

Tags: vhdl, slice, arithmetic-expressions

I want to multiply a U4.10 format fixed-point number by a U0.8 format constant and truncate my result to a U4.10. What I think I want is something like:

```
signal A, B : unsigned(13 downto 0);
signal MULT : unsigned(7 downto 0);
```

...

```
B <= (A * MULT)(21 downto 8);
```

But this doesn't compile. Two questions:

1. What is the proper syntax for what I'm trying to do?
2. Is there a nice way to use some symbolic attributes or somesuch to make the code more maintainable if I change the number of bits in my variable types?

Comment: Have you looked at the fixed point library? http://www.eda-stds.org/fphdl/

Comment: I haven't - thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Use an intermediate signal of the correct width. It's ugly but reliable and easy to maintain.

If you are doing this more than once, hide the ugliness in a function; if you have several functions or use them in more than one place, put them in a package.

For example;

```
package DSP is
   subtype Data  is unsigned(13 downto 0);
   subtype Coeff is unsigned(7 downto 0);

   function Mul_Coeff (A:Data, M:Coeff) return Data;
end package DSP;

package body DSP is
   function Mul_Coeff (A:Data, M:Coeff) return Data is
      variable Temp : unsigned (Coeff'Length + Data'High downto 0) := A * M;
   begin
      return Temp (Temp'High downto Coeff'Length);
   end Mul_Coeff;
end package body DSP;
```

...

```
B <= Mul_Coeff(A, Mult);
```

As you can see, this also uses the type system to protect you from changes in decisions about data word widths.

Later when you realise that rounding gives lower error than truncation, you only have to modify these functions...

Answer (score 2):

In case my comment above goes unnoticed by future readers:

There is a standard way to do this sort of activity - using the fixed point library from here:

http://eda-stds.org/fphdl

Answer (score 1):

IMO this calls for attributes:

```
procedure mul_fixed (
    signal a : in  unsigned_fixed;
    signal b : in  unsigned_fixed;
    signal c : out unsigned_fixed
    ) is
constant a_temp : unsigned(a'length - 1 downto 0) := to_unsigned(a);
constant b_temp : unsigned(b'length - 1 downto 0) := to_unsigned(b);
variable result : unsigned(a'length + b'length - 1 downto 0);
-- notice this might be negative if a, b are (? downto +n), which is correct
constant num_fractional : integer := 0 - a'right - b'right;
-- c integral might be bigger than integral/fractional part, make sure we only access valid indices in result
constant result_left    : integer := min(result'length - 1, num_fractional + c'left);
constant result_right   : integer := max(0                , num_fractional + c'right);
begin

    result := a_temp * b_temp;
    c <= (others => '0'); -- make sure all bits are defined
    c(result_left - num_fractional downto result_right - num_fractional) <= result(result_left downto result_right);

end procedure mul_fixed;
```

Where

```
type unsigned_fixed is array(range <>) of std_logic;
```

and conversion functions to/from unsigned exist.

So you would

```
...
signal a : unsigned_fixed( 3 downto -10); -- 4Q10
signal b : unsigned_fixed(-1 downto  -8); -- 0Q8
signal c : unsigned_fixed( 3 downto -10); -- 4Q10

mul_fixed(a, b, c);
```

I know all these attributes look scary at first, but I often found myself writing senselessly many packages just because I had different data types :-/
IMO one should spend time thinking about this once, figuring out a generic solution and move on -- that's what VHDL attributes are for, after all.

- Notice that I didn't have access to a test environment while writing this, so there may or may not need to be a type conversion when assigning result to c.

Also, you should probably at least take a look at a fixed-point library if you can. Or use VHDL-2008 with the fixed-point package.

Comment: The one you referred to was incorporated into VHDL-2008, but there were significant changes. It should work in VHDL-1993 with the above package, or with VHDL-2008 and the built-in package, depending on the vendor.